# Prototype declared in my header is not being seen in main, but other prototypes in the same header work fine

Tags: c, clang

I'm making a simple double-linked list in [list.c](https://github.com/maurymarkowitz/RetroBASIC/blob/glib-remove/src/list.c) with prototypes in [list.h](https://github.com/maurymarkowitz/RetroBASIC/blob/glib-remove/src/list.h), using Xcode as my IDE (so clang). There were about a dozen functions at first and I wrote a little `main` to call them for testing (ongoing, the code is not complete). I then added a new prototype to my .h and the implementation in the .c. It continued to work fine. Then I added a call to the new method in main to test it and got:

```
Implicit declaration of function 'lst_insert_sorted' is invalid in C99
```

Normally this means you forgot to `#include` the header or didn't write the proto, but that is not the case here. Functions declared and implemented before and after the new one in the source continue to work fine in main. Here is the prototype:

```
list_t* lst_insert_sorted(list_t *list, char *key, void *data);
```

Here's the first line in the implementation:

```
list_t* lst_insert_sorted(list_t *list, char *key, void *data)...
```

And here's how I call it in main (there are lots of similar bits that work fine):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "list.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  printf("Hello, World!\n");
  
  // try adding multiple items to a list
  list_t *listone = NULL;
  char *one = calloc(80, sizeof(char));
  strcpy(one, "one");
  char *two = calloc(80, sizeof(char));
  strcpy(two, "two");
  char *three = calloc(80, sizeof(char));
  strcpy(three, "three");
  char *four = calloc(80, sizeof(char));
  strcpy(four, "four");
  
  printf("There are %i items in the list at the start, expect 0\n", lst_length(listone));
  listone = lst_prepend(listone, one);
  listone = lst_prepend(listone, two);
  listone = lst_prepend(listone, three);
  listone = lst_prepend(listone, four);
  printf("There are %i items in the list after the inserts, expect 4\n", lst_length(listone));
  printf("Item 'three' is in location %d (zero indexed), expect 1 if prepend, 2 if append\n", lst_position(listone, three));
  
  // now try removing one
  lst_remove(listone, two);
  printf("There are %i items in the list after removing item two, expect 3\n", lst_length(listone));
  printf("Item 'three' is in location %d (zero indexed), expect 1 if prepend, 2 if append\n", lst_position(listone, three));

  // make a second list
  list_t *listtwo = NULL;
  char *five = calloc(80, sizeof(char));
  strcpy(five, "five");
  char *six = calloc(80, sizeof(char));
  strcpy(six, "six");
  listtwo = lst_append(listtwo, five);
  listtwo = lst_append(listtwo, six);
  printf("There are %i items in the second list\n", lst_length(listtwo));
  
  // and add it to the first one
  listone = lst_concat(listone, listtwo);
  printf("There are %i items in the concated list\n", lst_length(listone));
  
  // make a copy of the first list
  list_t *listthree = NULL;
  listthree = lst_copy(listone);
  printf("There are %i items in the copied list\n", lst_length(listthree));

  // dump the first list
  lst_free_everything(listone);
  listone = NULL;
  printf("There are %i items in the freed list\n", lst_length(listone));
  
  // make a sorted list
  list_t *listfour = NULL;
  char *ten = calloc(80, sizeof(char));
  strcpy(ten, "ten");
  char *eleven = calloc(80, sizeof(char));
  strcpy(eleven, "eleven");
  char *twelve = calloc(80, sizeof(char));
  strcpy(twelve, "twelve");
      
  listfour = lst_insert_sorted(listfour, "12", twelve);
  printf("There are %i items in the sorted list\n", lst_length(listfour));
  
  printf("Goodbye, World!\n");

  return 0;
}
```

I've cleared the build folders. If I change `lst_insert_sorted` to any other of the many functions, like `lst_insert_at_index` it compiles fine. There are no errors or warnings other than this one line.

Any ideas why it does not find the prototype for this **one** function?

Comment: Can you give us a minimal reproducible example? For instance remove other functions but post the rest of the code?

Comment: @Maury Markowitz, Temporarily add `list_t* lst_insert_sorted(list_t *list, char *key, void *data);` before `int main() { ...}` and report if that quiets the error.

Comment: There might be issues with the order in which you include headers. Or with your include guards or many other issues. Without an example we cannot tell.

Comment: Seems strange the files are called list.c, list.h, yet functions begin with `lst_`.   Looks error prone.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - yes, adding the proto in main does make the error go away.

Comment: @Gerhardh - I have added my complete main

Comment: Did you update your `list.h` in the correct folder? For testing you could remove another function from the header that is now used without any error like `lst_copy`.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz "Complete main" is the least useful piece of information. You need to post your **minimal** reproducing `list.h`, `list.c` and `main.c`

Comment: @Gerhardh - you got it... see "answer"

Comment: @EugeneSh. - i did post list h and c, they are linked.

Comment: You missed the "minimal" part. That means removing all parts that are not required to reproduce the issue. For your `main` that means 2 function calls (one for your error and one other from same header) would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

*SIGH*. This is an Xcode thing.

It appears if you copy files from one project to another it treats them differently depending on the type, regardless of what the add-new-file dialog suggests (copy if needed).

So for the header, it simply pointed to the original location, while the implementation it physically copied. There is no indication of this in the display and I only figured it out after Gerhardh's hint and then looked through the build output, which is normally hidden.

I suspect I'm not the first to encounter this, but it's not clear what one should search for - clearly the current subject is unlikely to be a "hit" for the other cases where this might happen.